# Parent-Child relation in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, parent-child

I would like to clear the concept of how children are deleted when they are created by `new`.

This code example is from http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html

```
ButtonWidget::ButtonWidget(QStringList texts, QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout;
    for (int i = 0; i < texts.size(); ++i) {
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(texts[i]);
        connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
        signalMapper->setMapping(button, texts[i]);
        gridLayout->addWidget(button, i / 3, i % 3);
    }

    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const QString &)),
            this, SIGNAL(clicked(const QString &)));

    setLayout(gridLayout);
}
```

1. `signalMapper`

   As it is constructed with parameter `this`, when the parent object `ButtonWidget` is deleted, it is also deleted.

   Is this correct?
2. `gridLayout`

   Why does the `gridLayout` not require to be created by `new QGridLayout(this)`?
3. `button`

   It is created in a for loop which mean it will be out of scope after each loop. Under normal situation, there should be memory leak if it is not deleted within the loop. So, does it make memory leak in this program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes. When a parent is specified for a `QObject`, it takes ownership of that object. When a parent object is deleted, it will delete all it's child objects (all objects that it owns);
2. The reason is that `setLayout` sets a layout for a widget *and* gives the ownership of this layout to the widget. So after `setLayout` is called, the grid layout is owned by the `ButtonWidget` and it will delete it when needed (i.e. when `ButtonWidget` itself will be deleted);
3. Same as 2, after `gridLayout->addWidget(button, i / 3, i % 3);` is called, the ownership of `button` will change. Technically, `addWidget` calls `addItem`, so a `QWidgetItem` is created. The layout takes ownership of that *item*, and the parent widget takes ownership of the *widget*. Anyway, the button will be destroyed on the destruction ot it's parent widget.

Comment: In this case, if I use `gridLayout = new QGridLayout(this)` and `QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(texts[i], this);` , will it cause any problem such as double deleting the object in the heap?

Comment: Technically layouts don't take ownerships of the widgets. They give the ownership to their own parents. So the owner of the `button` widgets will be `ButtonWidget` (`this`).

Comment: @tom No, but you might get a warning like `ButtonWidget already has a layout` when you call `setLayout(gridLayout);`.

Comment: Thanks. Some of the documentations specify the parent-child relation like `setCentralWidget()`: Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time.         But, some doesn't like `layout.addwidget()`.

Comment: @tom True. It has been explained in the [layout management](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts).